# Number of concurrent connections in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, browser, cross-browser, connection

Is there currently a way to programatically determine from within a Silverlight app the maximum number of concurrent connections that the browser will allow? I know I can do this on the server then pass it as a parameter, but I would like to know if its possible in Silverlight.

This is for all versions of Silverlight including Silverlight 4 RC.

Comment: I know it depends on the browser hence trying to do it programatically...

Answer (score -1):

You could make a js call to window.maxConnectionsPerServer in IE. I don't think there is a way in firefox. Even then, there might be a limitation on the webserver as to the max num of connections /client.

Comment: hmmm that's more along the lines of what I'd like but I need it to be cross browser.